# Jenkins: how to make an upstream job trigger the file system polling on a downstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins to build two jobs (A and B).
I want to trigger job B when a certain file F is updated by job A.
F is updated after about 10 minutes of completion of job A (it takes 10 minutes for the replication service to copy the file to the remote server where job B is going to execute)

So B is downstream job of A, but I can not trigger B as soon as A is finished since by that time F isnt updated on the server where B executes. 
I am currently using FS trigger plugin in B to check for F every minute, that seems to work well. But its just an overhead to keep checking for F all the time 24 hours. Instead I would like B to start polling the file system for file F when job A has finished, so then it will poll for roughly 10 minutes until the replication is complete and then will start building.

Does any one know how to accomplish something like this in Jenkins? Simply put, how to make an upstream job trigger the file system polling on a downstream job?

Regards,
-Safi

Comment: Are you also aware that you can set quiet time for a build, say for 10 minutes on job B. This means job B, when triggered as downstream project, will wait for 10 minutes before it actually starts building.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers guys. I ended up writting my own bash script and call it in the first line of Job B. The script can poll for M minutes for the file F and then exits with a SUCCESS exit status (which causes jenkins to continue the build) if the file is found or exits with an error if file isnt found within M minutes (which causes jenkins to quit the build). So something like this is in my jenkins job B:-

./myscript.sh -f file_to_poll -m minutes_to_poll_for

the line above would either return with success or failure

./start_build

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [ScriptTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin) in job B to monitor file F with a script. You can poll it every 5 minutes or so.

Write a shell or batch script that will compare F to it's previous state (keep the state as a copy or a time stamp) and trigger job B if a change is found.

I hope this helps.